# Is the word 'unpack' a valid grammatical term?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I have seen the word 'unpack' used to describe the analysing of syntax and semantic expressions.

The [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/215962?redirectedFrom=unpack#eid) does not list this usage of the word 'unpack'.

Is this a valid technical term in the examination of language ?

If so, what exactly should it convey and when was it first used in this sense ?

Comment: Can you provide a usage example of what you are referring to?

Comment: Look up the definition of "metaphor".

Comment: *"I have seen the word 'unpack' used to describe the analysing of syntax and semantic expressions."* and therefore you will be able to give a couple of examples in context - could you do that?

Comment: OED does too! "2.c. *transitive.* Originally *Philosophy*. To analyse (an issue or concept) in great detail, typically with the aim of uncovering its underlying assumptions or hidden implications. Later more generally: to analyse (a work, etc.) in order to interpret or understand it."

Comment: The French verb *decortiquer* is used conversationally, and does not have an exact English translation.  It’s possible that work on syntax and semantics with a Continental origin might have been seen words like this translated into words like *unpack.*

Comment: This question is erroneous. Both Lexico (and therefore the OED) ***do*** provide definitions of this sense. As a previous comment and an answer illustrate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this definition.

> **unpack**  *VERB*
> 1.2 Analyse (something) into its component elements.
> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/unpack)

It is not a technical term in the examination of language.  It is a general term, widely used.  (As noted by Hot Licks, a metaphor.)

Comment: Similarly Merriam Webster has this analytic use, which is, after all, a fairly obvious metaphorical usage.

Comment: Your answer is accepted. Thank you. 'Not a technical term in the examination of language' was my own understanding and findings. Merely a metaphor (used by some). Much appreciated.